# How can i prove this question without using The Mean Value Theorem?

Tags: analysis

Question:

Suppose $f'$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $\epsilon\gt0$.Prove that there exist $\delta\gt0$ such that $|\frac{f(t)-f(x)}{t-x}-f'(x)|\lt\epsilon$ whenever $0\lt|t-x|\lt\delta$,with $x$ and $t$ in $[a,b]$.

My question is how can I prove it without using The Mean Value Theorem.

Comment: Use the definition of $f'$.

Comment: It is probably impossible, because Mean Value Theorem is basically the only tool that allows to conclude properties of a function from properties of the derivative. One chance would be to use the Newton-Leibniz theorem, but its proof requires Mean Value Theorem too.

Comment: @Adayah I don't think so. Because $f'$ is continuous on compact set $[a, b]$, so it's finite at every point in this interval and the limit $\lim_{t \to x} \frac{f(t) - f(x)}{t - x}$ exists, and equals $f'(x)$. Therefore, by definition, for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $0 < |t - x| < \delta$ implies $|f'(x) - \frac{f(t) - f(x)}{t - x}| < \epsilon$. Is there an issue?

Comment: @on1921379 your choice of $\delta>0$ basically depends on $x$, which is not allowed in question.

Comment: Been a while, but isn't this just uniform continuity, which you get since $f'$ is continuous on a compact set?

Comment: @Alan It is not. If you think it is, try writing down an actual proof and if you succeed, I will be very interested to see it.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose it were false. Then there exists $r>0$ and there exist sequences $(t_n)_n$ and $(x_n)_n$ in $[a,b]$ with $t_n\ne x_n$ and with

$t_n,x_n$ both converging to some $y\in [a,b],$ and such that $$(*)\quad \left|\frac {f(t_n)-f(x_n)}{t_n-x_n}-f'(x_n)\right|>r$$ for every $n.$

Now $$\frac {f(t_n)-f(x_n)}{t_n-x_n}=\frac {1}{t_n-x_n}\int_{x_n}^{t_n}f'(u)du$$ is bounded above by $\max_{u\in [x_n,t_n]}f'(u)$ and bounded below by $\min_{u\in [x_n,t_n]}f'(u)$. So by $(*)$ there exists $u_n\in [x_n,t_n]$ with $$|f'(u_n)-f'(x_n)|>r.$$

But  $u_n$ and $x_n$ both converge to $y$ so $f'$ is not continuous at $y,$ a contradiction.

Comment: This is definitely a correct answer. For your information, this is actually Exercise 48.3 from the book *Foundations Of Mathematical Analysis* by Richard Johnsonbaugh and W. E. Pfaffenberger, but integration theory has not covered yet before that chapter, not even mean value theorem, I always think the authors have simply put the wrong order of the exercise.

Comment: @user284331. Interesting. Note that the upper & lower bounds for the integral, and the continuity of $f'$, gives us the MVT for the case when $f'$ is continuous, which is used in the 2nd half of the proof of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Comment: I think that instead of picking the sequences it is cleaner to just use the uniform continuity of $f'$ (which you basically prove) and proceed in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

*I had the same idea as Adayah's suggestion in his comment (which I hadn't read before) of DanielWainfleet's answer.*

Since $f'$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, it is uniformly continuous, hence there exists $\delta>0$ such that forall $u,x\in[a,b]$:
$$|u-x|<\delta\Longrightarrow|f'(u)-f'(x)|<\epsilon.$$
Then, forall $x,t\in[a,b]$ such that $0<|t-x|<\delta$:
$$\left|\frac{f(t)-f(x)}{t-x}-f'(x)\right|=\left|\frac1{t-x}\int_x^t(f'(u)-f'(x))\,\mathrm du\right|<\epsilon.$$